# Angular load controller after service has aquired a swagger api file

Tags: angularjs, swagger

I have a controller that uses a swagger-js enabled api. However the api is unavailable until the swagger library aquires the swagger sepcification file. I would like that the controller that has this as an API to load only after the swagger API is avaible and ready to use.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to keep your `controller` (did you mean `service`?) in an *initialization* phase while Swagger is getting configured.

I would do it by having a `$q` Promise which `resolves` when Swagger is configured and then design all other functions on the `controller` (I would write a `service` wrapper around it, though), to return Promises which depends on the `then` branch of the initialization promise.

---

The implementation will be something along these lines:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.service('swaggerService', ['$q', function ($q) {
  var deferred = $q.Promise(),
      initPromise = deferred.promise;

  // This function should be called when Swagger is done initializing.
  // It may be best to initialize Swagger here itself, if that is an option.
  swatterInitCb(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve();
    }
  });

  return {
    // This function will return a Promise.
    getData: function (dataId) {
      return initPromise.then(function (dataId) {
        // Use Swagger (which is now guaranteed to be intialised)
        // to get data from dataId
        return data;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, service which I afterwards inject in a controller, I want the service to be fully loaded when it's injected in the controller. Can you give me an example with the service which is wrapped in a promise?

Comment: @patentul I've added an example illustration. I haven't vetted the syntax but the rough idea should be clear from it.